# Grub unresponsive with high resolution

Tags: grub2

I am running grub (version 2.02) with a resolution of 2560x1440. Although this resolution is the `preferred mode` according to the `videoinfo` command, grub happens to be incredibly unresponsive/laggy in this configuration. A keystroke will show an effect only after ~1sec.

To provide a complete picture, my grub configuration file has the following options set:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1440
```

I do realize it is not necessary to run grub with such a high resolution, but I wonder if there is any way to make it work.

Comment: i always do `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="verbose splash"`.  It can often help seeing that info at boot time to diagnose various problems.

Comment: I suspect this might be a limitation of grub.  I doubt the authors saw fit to include hardware acceleration drivers on a bootloader so this might be re-rendering 3.5 million pixels every frame on the CPU.